# How to use sed to remove some characters from file?

Tags: shell, sed

I have this code in some file

```
<pre class="bbCodeCode" dir="ltr" data-xf-init="code-block" data-lang=""><code>-Fix numcer one/Two
-EMM Support
-Fix update &lt; broken
-Add support patch</code></pre>
</div>
</div><b><br />
```

I need to remove some characters and keep just this code

```
-Fix numcer one/Two
-EMM Support
-Fix update &lt; broken
-Add support patch
```

I have try this code

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -n '/>-/,/</p' /home/Desktop/1 > /home/Desktop/2
sed -n '/^-*code>/p' /home/raed/Desktop/2  > /home/Desktop/3
sed -i 's#</code></pre>##' /home/Desktop/3
exit
```

But the code remove first line

```
-Fix numcer one/Two
```

Comment: Thank you .. But awk, does not work properly on busybox of E2 devices ... I need sed ...

Comment: Please try my 2nd solution I have added a `sed` version now. Also we could discuss in my answer's comments for same, cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
sed 's/<[^>]*>//g' <file
```

It will remove everything between `<` and the next `>` (linewise).

Answer (score 1):

***1st solution:*** Try GNU `awk` for this one. With your shown samples please try following `awk` code.

```
awk -v RS="^$" '
match($0,/(^|\n)<pre class="[^"]*".*<code>-(.*)<\/code>/,arr){
  print arr[2]
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:***  Simple explanation would be, using GNU `awk`'s capability to make `RS` `^$` and then using its `match` function to match regex `(^|\n)<pre class="[^"]*".*<code>-(.*)<\/code>`(explained later in this answer). This regex creates 2 capturing groups and all matched values are getting stored into array named `arr`. So if regex has matched values then I am simply printing 2nd element of array `arr` by using `arr[2]` to get desired values.

---

---

***2nd solution:*** With `sed` using `-z` and `-E` options please try following code.

```
sed -zE 's/(^|\n)<pre class="[^"]*".*<code>-(.*)<\/code>.*/\2/' Input_file
```

***OR*** if your `sed` version supports `\n` then with a slight change in above `sed` code you can have as follows:

```
sed -zE 's/(^|\n)<pre class="[^"]*".*<code>-(.*)<\/code>.*/\2\n/' Input_file
```

---

---

***3rd solution:*** With GNU `grep` please try following code:

```
grep -zoP '(^|\n)<pre class="[^"]*".*?<code>-\K(.*?\n[^\n]+)+(?=</code>)'  Input_file
```

---

---

***4th solution:*** If you really want to go with your approach(looks like you don't have GNU version of `sed`) then Let me try with your approach here but this will be very straight forward `sed` with little less validations for data compare to previous solutions of mine but this will do the job for you in case your sample Input_file is always same.

```
sed -En '/^<pre class/s/^<pre class="[^"]*".*<code>-(.*)$/\1/p; /^-/{s/<\/code>.*//; p}'  Input_file
```

Comment: `sed: invalid option -- 'z'` does not work and with just `-e` not change.

Comment: @fairman, ahhhh looks like you don't have GNU sed. Could you please try this grep solution, added into my solution now.

Comment: The E2 Busybox is limited work .. last solution also does not work

Comment: @fairman, Trust me if your `sed`'s `-z` option is not working it could be difficult though we can do substitution but validations part could be tricky. How about using this `awk`, which should work in your system I believe: `awk -v RS= 'match($0,/(^|\n)<pre class="[^"]*".*<code>-(.*)<\/code>/){split(substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH),arr,"<code>-|</code>");print arr[2]}'  Input_file` Let me know how `grep` and this `awk` went, cheers.

Comment: This code for `awk -v RS= 'match($0,/(^|\n)<pre class="[^"]*".*<code>-(.*)<\/code>/){split(substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH),arr,"<code>-|</code>");print arr[2]}'  Input_file` give just first line `-Correction for ICAM ECMs for NDS`

Comment: @fairman, I have added simple `sed` actually fixing your approach, you can try all of these solutions and let me know how it goes. cheers.

Comment: @fairman, With my 4th solution `sed` one we need not to run so many `sed`s we can do it in a single shot, kindly try it once and let me know how it goes.